# opencv serialization with nested sequence

Tags: xml, opencv, xml-serialization, yaml

I have the following situation:

```
typedef struct {
    int value;
    string color;
} PositionElement;

struct {
   int row;
   int column;
   vector<PositionElement> positionElements;  // has 120 values
}     PositionInformation;
```

How can I use opencv serialization on this?  The samples/tutorials/documentation don't have an example of squences nested inside structs.

I start having trouble when attempting to implement this function:

```
void PositionInformation::read(const FileNode &node);
```

I can't figure out how to iterate through the positionElements to populate them.

Comment: Could you post your code for serialization? Deserialization depends on in.

Comment: I abandonded all the individual struct serialize/deserialize code, so I can't post it.  Went with a much simpler approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping to add the serialization functions directly into those structs, like is suggested in the documentation: adding read()/write() functions to the structs and global read()/write() too with FileNodes and the new datatypes as inputs.  I thought that would be slick so that I could then have my higher level app just serialize/deserialize the PositionInformation struct.

However since I'm the only one who is going to use those structs, I decided to just follow the examples of writing data to XML/YAML on the C++ cheatsheet, which do not add serialization to individual structs, but do read/write collections containing sequences, and that worked fine.  What I was trying to do was overkill anyway.